# Find a specific url <a> through regex

Tags: html, regex

I need a specific regex pattern to find a URL in web pages in HTML

For example, I would like to search for this url: `domainurl.com`

and these are the URLs with tags

```
<a href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/">fsdf</a>
<a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">fgddf</a>
<a href="https://www.domainurl.com/page/pago">domain </a>
```

using this code regex

```
<a.*?[^>]* href="((https?:\/\/)?([\w\-])+\.{1}domainurl\.([a-z]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?)"
```

what congra get to get this label , I suppose to have target = `"_ blank" rel = "nofollow noopener"`

```
<a title="Google Adsense" href="https://www.domainurl.com/refer/google-adsense/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">fgddf</a>
```

Is there any regex code for target = "_ blank" and rel = "nofollow noopener" ??

this is what I have
https://regexr.com/49hne

Comment: Better use `xpath` queries instead.

Comment: Have a quick read here [regex html parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complete URL using `positive lookbehind`:

```
(?<=\<a.*?href=\")(.*?\..*?\.[a-z]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/197)

Only `domainurl.com`  using `positive lookbehind`:

```
(?<=\<a.*?www\.)([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)
```

[DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/198)

For `target = "_ blank" and rel = "nofollow noopener"` :

[DEMO3](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/199)

```
target.*?\".*\"
```

For `domainurl.com` and `target = "_ blank" and rel = "nofollow noopener"` :

[DEMO4](https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/200)

Comment: failed to implement it :(  <a.*?[^>]* href="((https?:\/\/)?([\w\-])+\.{1}domainurl\.([a-z]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?)" target.*?\".*\"

Comment: @juan see DEMO4 please